# Why is db connection closed after trying and failing to get a lock with spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I would like to wrap a PessimisticLockingFailureException that gets thrown in a jpa repo when trying to get a lock for an entity that is already locked. And handle the wrapped exception in my exception handlers.

But it seems that when spring tries to end the transaction the connection is already closed and spring throws a new exception that overwrites the exception I would like to see.

In the logs I get "Application exception overridden by rollback exception" and it is this I would like to avoid. (Cause of rollback ex is that "Connection is closed")

Is there a solution to this? Or am I doing something wrong?

(Here's some pseudo code of what I'm doing)

```
  String restControllerMethod(String args) {
    try {
      return service.serviceMethod(args);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      throw e1; // org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException caused by org.hibernate.TransactionException caused by java.sql.SQLException
    }
  }

  @Transactional
  String serviceMethod(String args) {
    Entity entity;
    try {
      entity = repo.repoFindMethod(args);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
      throw new WrappingException(e2); // org.springframework.dao.PessimisticLockingFailureException caused by org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException
    }
    // do some processing with entity
    return result;
  }

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
  String repoFindMethod(String args);
```

I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.2.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-web spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and an emmbedded h2 db

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding a com.zaxxer.hikari.SQLExceptionOverride implementation and pointing the
`spring.datasource.hikari.exception-override-class-name` to it.

This causes hikari to not close the connection when the db throws an exception with the specified error code.

I've also added `@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "0")})` to the locking query since default lock wait times can be vendor specific

The issue with this solution is that it is vendor specific (both for h2 and hikari). And not all vendors support a custom timeout for obtaining locks (h2 for example does not support this but it matters less since it's timeout is very short anyway)

Example of my solution (for h2):

`spring.datasource.hikari.exception-override-class-name=com.example.H2SQLExceptionOverride`

```
public class H2SQLExceptionOverride implements SQLExceptionOverride {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(H2SQLExceptionOverride.class);
  public static final int LOCK_TIMOUT_ERROR_CODE = 50200;

  @java.lang.Override
  public Override adjudicate(SQLException sqlException) {
    if (sqlException.getErrorCode() == LOCK_TIMOUT_ERROR_CODE) {
      logger.debug("Diverting from default hikari impl and continuing transaction with errorCode: "
          + sqlException.getErrorCode() + " and sqlState: " + sqlException.getSQLState());
      return Override.DO_NOT_EVICT;
    }
    return Override.CONTINUE_EVICT;
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention that the issue with this solution is that it is vendor specific. Is the issue itself vendor specific as well? If so, that invalidates the issue with the solution.

Comment: The issue is vendor specific in the way that the implementation of hikari has chosen that lock timout exception warrant a closing of the db connection, which I don't necessarily want. And I could imagine a way that I don't need to concern myself with the details and just say to spring that I don't want connections closed for lock timout exceptions (so I don't need to create a class for each db vendor and I'm not bound to hikari).